# MongoDB Realm: React Native does not persist login / sessions after app restart

Tags: mongodb, react-native, realm, mongodb-realm

I am following the Task Tracker tutorial and I am not able to persist the login session. I am able to register and login, however, everytime I close the app and open it again, it redirects me to the login screen.

https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/react-native/

In addition, I use AuthProvider to read user, I get “null”.

Anyone have any ideas? Do I have to write custom logic to persist login information / session tokens?

Thanks

Comment: Share some of your relevant code.